# nrf51822 / YJ-14015 Blinky

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf51

I am trying to build a simply first `blinky`on a [nrf51822 china clone (YJ-14015)](https://falba.tech/product/yj-14015-module-core51822b-clone/), as part of building a [redox wireless](https://github.com/mattdibi/redox-w-firmware) and debugging why the BLE communication does not work.

As SDK I use [`nrf5_SDK_11`](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v11.0.0%2Findex.html) as the keyboards custom firmware is based on it.

Now I tried a very minimal example blinky with `main.c`

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "nrf_delay.h"
#include "nrf_gpio.h"

#define LED_PIN_1 1           // LED connected to pin 1       

/* --> from nrf5_SDK_11/components/drivers_nrf/hal/nrf_gpio.h
__STATIC_INLINE void nrf_gpio_pin_set(uint32_t pin_number)
{
    NRF_GPIO->OUTSET = (1UL << pin_number);
}

__STATIC_INLINE void nrf_gpio_pin_clear(uint32_t pin_number)
{
    NRF_GPIO->OUTCLR = (1UL << pin_number);
}
*/

int main(void)
{

    // Make LED pin an output pin
    nrf_gpio_cfg_output(LED_PIN_1);
    nrf_gpio_pin_set(LED_PIN_1);

    // Toggle LEDs.
    while (true)
    {
        // Down
        NRF_GPIO->OUTCLR = (NRF_GPIO->OUT & (1UL << LED_PIN_1));
        // nrf_gpio_pin_clear(LED_PIN_1);
        nrf_delay_ms(1000);

        // Up
        NRF_GPIO->OUTSET= (NRF_GPIO->OUT | (1UL << LED_PIN_1));
        // nrf_gpio_pin_set(LED_PIN_1);
        nrf_delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

My expectation would have been that I can see the voltage flip every second from high to low to high etc on `PIN 01`... Unfortunately I only get a `1.55 V` vs ground if I attach it to my multi meter, but the voltage just stays constant and nothing changes. Anything I did wrong with this loop?

For flashing I use a  [ST-LinkV2 clone](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32992358875.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.6dd62fceIhXTGL&algo_pvid=7b0c5351-2257-4315-8a2f-390e4f2ee027&algo_exp_id=7b0c5351-2257-4315-8a2f-390e4f2ee027-2) + the docker containers for openocd and the toolchain of the [redox wireless](https://github.com/mattdibi/redox-w-firmware) project, which basically uses telnet over openocd. After adjusting for the right paths, flashing seems successful and as mentioned above, `PIN 01` can be set to `1.55V`, so I assume there is no problem with the flashing itself.

Comment: The fact that your multimeter measures around half the expected voltage (3.3 V I assume) tells that the output is likely toggling between 0 and 1. Just way faster than you were expecting, maybe something is not right with the `nrf_delay_ms` function. I don't know about the NRF SDK, but maybe there is some init function that must be called to setup clocks etc. before using the delay function.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to validate it by just setting the `PIN  01` outside of the while loop and then not changing it. Unfortunately this still just raises it to `1.5V`. For what it is worth, all other pins are at approx `300mV` - besides `SWCLK` which is at `3.3V`.  Also I tried to raise other pins with the same effect. The raised ones are at `1.5V` all others at `300mV`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else stumbles across the same difficulties:

After quite a while, I figured out a way to fix the `blinky` example for the `yj-14015`. The key was to adjust the `Makefile` which I took from the [nordic SDK](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v11.0.0%2Findex.html) according to the [Makefile in the redox firmware](https://github.com/mattdibi/redox-w-firmware/blob/master/redox-w-receiver-basic/custom/armgcc/Makefile).

The relevant lines being as follows:

```
#flags common to all targets
CFLAGS  = -DNRF51
CFLAGS += -DGAZELL_PRESENT
CFLAGS += -DBOARD_CUSTOM
CFLAGS += -DBSP_DEFINES_ONLY
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m0
CFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs --std=gnu99
CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror -O3 -g3
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-function
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-variable
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=soft
# keep every function in separate section. This will allow linker to dump unused functions
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing
CFLAGS += -fno-builtin --short-enums


# Assembler flags
ASMFLAGS += -x assembler-with-cpp
ASMFLAGS += -DNRF51
ASMFLAGS += -DGAZELL_PRESENT
ASMFLAGS += -DBOARD_CUSTOM
ASMFLAGS += -DBSP_DEFINES_ONLY
```

Here would be the full [Makefile](https://github.com/matthiasdold/yj_14015_blinky_Makefile/tree/main).